# Apache Camel Kinesis pause/resume throws ExpiredIteratorException

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-kinesis

I've a Camel route that gets the record from a Kinesis stream. I accidentally paused the route and enabled it 10 minutes later. The Kinesis iterator expires after 5 min. Eventhough the route is resumed, the Camel/Kinesis component seems to be holding on the expired iterator and is unable to get records from the kinesis stream. Is there any way to fix the issue without a restart?

> amazonKinesisClient=%23KinesisClient&iteratorType=AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER&maxResultsPerRequest=100&sequenceNumber=4957961397643123123123123933769851155815690236067842&shardId=shardId-000000000000.
>   Will try again at next poll.  Caused by:
>   [com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ExpiredIteratorException -
>   Iterator expired. The iterator was created at time Thu Mar 22 02:32:32
>   UTC 2018 while right now it is Thu Mar 22 03:54:44 UTC 2018 which is
>   further in the future than the tolerated delay of 300000 milliseconds.
>   (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   ExpiredIteratorException; Request ID:
>   f5434586-4645-45d9-a66a-1232d2e45678)]

Comment: Can you try to stop/start the route instead of suspend/resume - then it may close/recreate resources. And what version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Thank you Claus. Camel version is 2.18.0. The issue occurred in production and we didn't have the code in place to stop/start a route. It was doing suspend/resume instead. Will do the changes to take care of issues in the future. Camel is bundled in a spring boot app. Is there an actuator endpoint to stop/start a route to resolve the current issue?

Comment: Not sure if they are in that old version, but yeah there is /camel/routes acutator endpoints. Check the source code of your versions to see what it has